# How to select approximated intersection area, of three annuli.

Tags: geometry, optimization, area

I am doing a localization project based on signal strength trilateration. For this, I need to find some algorithms that select the intersection area, or if there is none, select an approximated intersection area.

The signal strength is converted to a radial distance from the base station and has a deviation margin.

If the all three annuli have a common intersection, that area is selected. See Figure 1:
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLfwu.png)

If the annuli overlap each other too much so that there is no common intersection area for all annuli, one area outside the annulus' margins, but are bounded of the annulus' margins, is selected. See Figure 2:
[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jznyZ.png)

I am using Matlab and can get all the circle-intersection cooridnates but need to find a way of detecting which type of case it is, and also find the *best** area.

If it easier to get the centroid point of that area instead, that will also work!

$*$ *best = the area that is closest for all circles to get a common intersection in*)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with ring-theory or localization, as far as I can see. I did my best to substitute more appropriate alternatives.

Comment: what you mean is annulus, not ring. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)

Comment: Thanks for the corrections.